# How to programmatically navigate between data points on a Dygraph?

Tags: dygraphs

I would like to offer a feature that is very similar to the mouse-hover event that will highlight datapoints based on the coordinates of the mouse.

However, instead of the datapoints being highlighted via the mouse coords, I would like to allow the user to click a Left-arrow/Right-arrow button (a Previous/Next button kind of idea) and as the user clicks the button, the highlighted circle will move left/right.

[This Flot fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKLcD/) is an example of the navigation feature I would like to do in Dygraphs.

Does Dygraphs offer this feature out-of-the-box or will I need to build my own function for this? If there is native support, can you point me to an example? If I have to do this manually, can you let me know how to programmatically highlight datapoints that fall on a specific X-axis tick? (I'm using a date/time x-axis).

Here's the fiddle code

```
$(function() {

    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 31; i += 1) {
        d1.push([i, Math.random() * 10]);
    }

    var highlightPoint = 15;
    var xmin = 10, xmax = 20;


    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1 ],
               {
                   xaxis:{min: xmin, max: xmax}
                });
    plot.highlight(0,highlightPoint);

    $('#prevPoint').click(function(){
        plot.unhighlight(0,highlightPoint);
        highlightPoint -= 1;
        xmin = highlightPoint - 5;
        xmax = highlightPoint + 5;
        plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].min = xmin;
        plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].max = xmax;
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();  
        plot.highlight(0,highlightPoint);
    });

    $('#nextPoint').click(function(){
        plot.unhighlight(0,highlightPoint);
        highlightPoint += 1;
        xmin = highlightPoint - 5;
        xmax = highlightPoint + 5;
        plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].min = xmin;
        plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].max = xmax;
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();  
        plot.highlight(0,highlightPoint);        
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dygraphs has a `.setSelection()` and `.getSelection()` method that allows us to programmatically highlight a particular datapoint.

In addition, Dygraphs has the `.layout_.points` that returns an array of all the visible datapoints.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggtt2e5w/) on how to programmatically navigate through visible datapoints.

*One flaw with the example is there is no auto-panning when the highlighted datapoint reaches the end of the visible datapoints.*

```
g = new Dygraph(

  // containing div
  document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
  "Date,Temperature\n" +
  "2008-05-01,65\n" +
  "2008-05-02,70\n" +
  "2008-05-03,74.2\n" +
  "2008-05-04,75\n" +
  "2008-05-05,70\n" 
);

function navigateThroughDygraphDatapoints(navigationDirection) {
  var moveRight = (navigationDirection != null && navigationDirection === 'right');
  var currentSelectedDatapoint = g.getSelection();

  if (currentSelectedDatapoint < 0) {
    currentSelectedDatapoint = g.layout_.points[0][0].idx;
  }
  if (moveRight) {
    currentSelectedDatapoint++;
  } else {
    currentSelectedDatapoint--;
  }

  g.setSelection(currentSelectedDatapoint);
}

document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function() {var dir = "left"; navigateThroughDygraphDatapoints(dir);},false);
document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function() {var dir = "right";navigateThroughDygraphDatapoints(dir);},false);
```